# User cannot see DevOps organisation

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops

I have a new DevOps organisation which is connected to AAD for authentication. I have added a user to the organisation but he cannot see it in Visual Studio. The first time he signed into DevOps via browser it configured a new personal organisation for him and he can see this organisation in Visual Studio. When he signs into DevOps with his account he can only see his personal default organisation but not the business organisation. If he browses directly to dev.azure.com/(organisationname) he can see the project and access this.
Please could you advise how we can correct this so he can see our org from his login and VS

Comment: May I know this status after the weekend? Does this users could see org successfully now?

Answer (score 1):

> The first time he signed into DevOps via browser it configured a new
>   personal organisation for him.

This is more like that this user's directory is not correct.

Let this user `https://aex.dev.azure.com/me` page, and then confirm he is locating in the correct directory which is your AAD owned.

For example, Microsoft is the directory that my company's AAD owned. Then I must located in this directory so that I can access the work organizations successfully:

[image]

---

> he cannot see it in Visual Studio

Similar with above, please ensure the account is login succeed in Visual Studio.

As he has been added as a member of your AAD and org, then the **account icon** showed in VS should same like the red one which shown below:

[image]

The account he signed in VS must be the one added in AAD, then he would succeed to see the organizations from visual studio.

---

*If all of above does not work for this account. Since stackoverflow is a open forum and not secure to share some org and account info [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/post.html?space=21), I'd suggest you share your issues here. Then attach your `organization name`, `AAD name`, `issue account` there.*